# After update of the JSON module i get the following warning

Tags: json, perl

After update of the JSON module from version 1.54 to 2.07 i get the following warning in my logs:

```
Prototype mismatch: sub ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::PerlRun::mypath_myfile_2epl::from_json: none vs ($@) at mypath_myfile.pl line 6.
Prototype mismatch: sub ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::PerlRun::mypath_myfile_2epl::to_json: none vs ($@) at mypath_myfile.pl line 6.
Prototype mismatch: sub ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::PerlRun::mypath_myfile_2epl::encode_json: none vs ($) at mypath_myfile.pl line 6.
Prototype mismatch: sub ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::PerlRun::mypath_myfile_2epl::decode_json: none vs ($) at mypath_myfile.pl line 6.
```

in line 6 of myfile.pl `use JSON;` is called

Any ideas what's going wrong here or how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide mypath_myfile.pl?

Comment: sry, in line 6 of this file 'use JSON;' is called

Comment: What version of JSON::XS do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Check the incompabilities between JSON 1 .x and 2.x at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.57/lib/JSON.pm#INCOMPATIBLE_CHANGES_TO_OLD_VERSION).
What do you include before JSON? Which modperl version are you running?

Comment: i had a look at the incompatibilities at CPAN before - nothing. Before 'use JSON;' geets called there only "use strict;" gets set. The mod_peal version is 2.000004

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you also need to update your JSON::XS and/or JSON::PP to a compatible version.